# SQL Server Trigger DELETE only a few records

Tags: sql-server

I have a table:

```
| id(int) | isActive(bit) |
```

and then I delete some records from the table.

```
delete from table 
where id in (1, 5, 8, 3)
```

Now I'd like to have a trigger or some other functionality which checks if you try to delete some ids which are active and skip those.

Sure I could create a stored procedure, but what if someone deletes something from the table not using that stored procedure?

And I could do a rollback in the trigger if any record was active.

But I'd like the user to be able to delete those that was not active and just "cancel" the delete on the records that was active.

Or is this even possible?

Comment: Trigger will be executed AFTER delete and can only make commit or rollback all. You can rollback whole transaction inside trigger and perform own delete excluding active records, but it will have bad impact on performance

Comment: And what did you try? Did you check the syntax for triggers? Do you have a specific question or are you asking for a link to the docs for triggers?

Comment: @vitalygolub that's not correct. There are both AFTER and INSTEAD OF triggers since 2005 at least

Comment: The safe way is to write a stored procedure and *deny* DELETE rights to the table, forcing people to use the stored procedure. Or create an updatable view (a simple SELECT all WHERE Active=0) and again, deny access to the table itself.

Comment: This sort of thing is normally handled by relational constraints - records that cannot be deleted because other records in foreign tables depend on them. It wouldn't meet your requirement of deleting some and not others thou; the whole statement would fail. What is perhaps unusual is that you're asking for his feature; is something about the existing and well used mechanisms not meeting your requirements?

Comment: Personally, yes, I agree, you should be forcing users to use the stored procedure, which can easily be achieved by giving `public` the `DENY` permission on `DELETE` for that table. That stops everyone apart from SAs and DBOs from deleting from that table. If you want to use a trigger, there's probably no need to roll back (if ID1 is active, you probably still want to delete ID 2 and 3). So use an `INSTEAD OF` trigger, and then just delete the rows that are no longer active.